# Is tacit programming possible in Purescript?

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

Is tacit programming also known as point-free style see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming an option in Purescript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the PureScript [Prelude source](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-prelude/blob/master/src/Prelude.purs), I'd say so:

```haskell
instance functorFn :: Functor ((->) r) where
  map = compose  -- point-free!
```

Your example in http://try.purescript.org/?session=3538ae1c-eece-8f50-ad0c-e1504846a793:

```haskell
foldr f z Nil = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (subfold xs)
  where subfold = foldr f z

sum = foldr (+) 0

main = trace $ show $ sum (1:2:3:4:Nil)  -- prints: 10
```

(needed to define foldr myself because I could not import any modules)

Comment: So how would you translate e.g the Wikipedia Haskell example : "sum  = foldr (+) 0"?

Comment: @user22207: see my edit, the syntax is exactly the same as in Haskell.

Comment: Writing recursive functions in point-free style does not seem to work the same as in Haskell though, because in Haskell you'd use the Y combinator for that (`fix f = let x = f x in x`), which needs lazy evaluation.